# HTML CSS Font Customization Issue

Tags: html, css, fonts, customization

My font customization only seems to work for one of the fonts. I'm not really sure why this happening.

---

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'blackjackregular';
    src: url("Fonts\black_jack-webfont.eot");
    src: url("Fonts\black_jack-webfont.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'basictitlefont';
    src: url("Fonts\basictitlefont-webfont.eot");
    src: url("Fonts\basictitlefont-webfont.ttf");
    src: url("Fonts\basictitlefont-webfont.woff");
}
h1
{
    font-family: 'basictitlefont';
}
```

For the blackjackregular, my code works. But once i change the h1 part to basictitlefont, it doesn't work. I can't seem to find any syntax issues and I don't know what the cause of this is.
All the basictitlefont and blackjackregular font files are in the same folder. I also tried using font squirrel but it didn't work.

Comment: What are these fonts? Where were they got from, and how were the font files generared? What does “doesn’t work” mean?

Comment: is basictitlefont correctly installed on the system?

Comment: Is the basictitlefont not working on h1 tags only or is it not working anywhere?  If it is only a problem on h1 tags, my guess is that some other CSS is overriding that rule.  If you can't use the font anywhere, then the files are probably not loading correctly.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Both of these fonts are installed on my computer and are in the same folder as the html/css files. basic title font is not working anywhere, even outside the h1 tags. They don't show up when html page is run.

Comment: @dmullings  Both of these fonts are installed on my computer and are in the same folder as the html/css files. basic title font is not working anywhere, even outside the h1 tags. They don't show up when html page is run.

Comment: @DouglasGrim Both of these fonts are installed on my computer and are in the same folder as the html/css files. basic title font is not working anywhere, even outside the h1 tags. They don't show up when html page is run.

Comment: In addition to my previous questions: what do the browser’s console log and network log (in Developer Tools) say?

Comment: so in between the <h1> tags I wrote "Hello" The browser displays "Hello", except that the font doesn't work. It's just in standard font. @JukkaK.Korpela